# A little bit political

Tags: cryptic-clues

An easy one:

> She talks about Trump and lies? (6, 7)

.

> Hopefully the question mark is enough of a "the compiler is playing silly buggers" indicator.

Comment: If this is referring to President Donald Trump, this could get really political here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you mean...

> Stormy Daniels:
>  1) She talks about Trump
>  2) "and lies" is a *stormy* (i.e. mixed-up) "Daniels" (thanks @Rubio)

Comment: Getting warmer. If it's an anagram, there should be an anagrind somewhere, right?

Comment: [This should be it...](http://www.webutils.pl/index.php?idx=rot&mode=rot13&dec=DECODE&data=FGBEZL+QNAVRYF%3B++%22Fur+gnyxf+nobhg+Gehzc%22+%28%2Aqrs.%2A%29.++Erirefr+jbeqcynl+vf+%22fgbezl%22+%28nantevaq%29+Qnavryf+%E2%86%92+%22naq+yvrf%22.)

Comment: That's correct, @Rubio. Want to post your own answer for the tick?

Comment: @RupertMorrish gnovice got the answer, I just properly interpreted the wordplay based on the observations in their post.  I'm happy to let gnovice complete their solution and have the tick.